# Can iPhone app be time-limited?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, appstore-approval

it is OK for me to publish an app on the app store which is time limited ? meaning the user can download it for free and use it for one month and then it will lock-up until he/she purchase the full app ?

is there an apple policy which says I can't ? can you give me a link to that clause ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at guideline #2.9 at [Apple's review guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html). It's always a judgement call, of course.

Answer (score 2):

In general, No.  Expiring trial apps are not allowed.

There might be exceptions for certain kinds of subscription services.